# Objective-C: self = nil doesn't set instance to null value

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, self

I've got the next code, pretty simple:

```
//SecondViewController.m
if(contentRvController==nil){
    contentRvController = [[ContentView alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"ContentView" bundle:nil]; //ContentView is a custom UIViewController
    ....
    [self.view addSubview:contentRvController.view];
}
else{
    contentRvController.view.hide = YES;
    [contentRvController release];
    contentRvController = nil;
}
```

Basically, when the code is launched from a button, if the UIViewController does not exist, create one and display it (it is meant to be displayed on a main bigger desktop view, this is the SecondViewController view). If it is already opened, close it and remove it to free resources.

Now, contentRvController is an instance of ContentView, a custom UIViewController. It has it's own close UIButton which IBAction is this:

```
//ContentView.m
- (IBAction) closeView {
    self.view.hidden = YES;
    [self release];
    self = nil;
}
```

Now, when triggered from SecondViewController, releasing contentRvController works properly (or so it seems to me), the view appears and disappears. But when the ContentView close button is tapped it also closes the view, but when trying to open it again the `if(contentRvController==nil)` returns `FALSE`, so I have to tap twice the button to execute in order to display again the ContentView.

It seems to me that `self = nil;` works different than `contentRvController = nil;` although it is supposed both points to the same place, and im lost with this.

¿Any idea? Cheers from México

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work the same way, but they're not doing what you think they do. The `=` does not affect the object; it affects the variable pointing to the object. Setting one variable to point to nil won't change the value of any other variables in your program. Similarly:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
b = 6;
printf("A is %d and B is %d\n", a, b);
```

This will print "A is 5 and B is 6" — because setting B to a new value doesn't change the value of A.

Comment: I get that, but since in this case `self`shouldn't be the same as contentRvController, which is an instance of ContentView?

What should I do, then .-. ?

Comment: Nope;  you don't get it. :)  contentRvController is *a copy* of the address of the object.  Just like `self` is a local variable that contains *a copy* of the address of the object.  The two variables are entirely decoupled;  having nothing to do with each other.  Changing one will not change the other.

Comment: ahhh, I see xD, think I need some sleep, for that silly mistake. Finally I found a workaround `(ContentRvController == nil || ContentRvController.view.hidden == YES)` is not what I meant to do in the first place, but it works. Guess next to do is the proper memory releases.

Answer (score 1):

No object should release itself. The normal way to dispose of an object is to implement -dealloc where you release any ivars, then call [super dealloc] like this.

```
- (void) dealloc; {  

[someIvar release];  
[someOtherIvar release];  
[super dealloc];  
}
```

You should definitely take a step back and read up on the object lifecycle in Objective-C, else a world of bugs await you. Apple's **View Controller Programming Guide for iOS** is not long at all. Just Google for that title. Save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: "No object should release itself." That's not true. `init` is allowed to release itself and return a different object.