# Can I use self = nil in my methods?

Tags: objective-c

Can I use

```
self = nil
```

in an instance method so that when the method execution ends, I can use an if statement in the main class:

```
if (myInstance)
```

to check if something went wrong ?

thanks

Comment: This isn't going to do what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767916/objective-c-self-nil-doesnt-set-instance-to-null-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do that, but it does *not have the effect you want*.

consider your objc method's signature for `-[NSArray count]` to have the following C function signature:

```
NSUInteger NSArray_count(NSArray * self, SEL _cmd) {
   self = nil; // ok - this is a variable, local to the function (method).
               // now all messages to `self` will do nothing - in this method only.
   ...
}
```

since the pointer you assign to nil is a variable local to the method, it does not actually affect the instance externally. it changes the pointer variable in the method's scope. that variable is the argument passed. in effect, it means that you have set the local argument to nil, but the rest of the world does not acknowledge this change.

Comment: I see! So if I've understood well, I can only set the external pointer (from the invoking method) to nil if my method is returning nil. If my method is not returning anything, then I'm only changing the local variable... (Although I can release the object)

Comment: *So if I've understood well, I can only set the external pointer (from the invoking method) to nil if my method is returning nil.*

in that case, the external pointer is simply reassigned (e.g. by the result of alloc+init). 

*If my method is not returning anything, then I'm only changing the local variable.*

exactly.
 (cont)

Comment: (cont) 
*Although I can release the object*

exactly. all messages affect the object passed as self *but* if you reassign self to nil in the body of the method, then self's true address will not be accessible after that point (unless of course you have copied the address in another local variable). to assign self to nil in a method's implementation is equivalent to saying "I don't want to message self in this invocation of this method any longer", and there are clearer, more idiomatic ways to write that so... i suggest a clear program will assign self only in initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `nil` in the constructor, yes. If you do this after calling the `[super init]` be sure you `release` the object it returned with an owning retain count.

With that said, something else you can do is follow Apple's usage of `*NSError` to go along with returning `nil` to help provide better information of what went wrong to your using code.

Comment: Actually my method isn't a constructor. Just a class method.. and something goes wrong I need indeed to release the object and not only  set it to nil. So, is it ok if I use it in a method which is not an initializer ?

Comment: Yes, you can return `nil` in your class method just as you would from a constructor. The process is nearly identical.

Comment: ok. One last question: if the method is not returning an object, then even if I set self = nil, I'm just changing a local variable ?

Comment: If this is in a class method, then `self` doesn't point to an instance, it points to the class object. @Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can return nil from a constructor, but if you return nil the maybe-allocated memory will never be freed!

If you're object manages its own life-cycle (and thus memory management), you can release it and return nil from a specific method.
Usually that kind of methods are class method, because if it isn't it involve that the user has a reference to the object, and thus it is hazardous to release it.