# Handling PVR textures for OpenGL ES 2 (the real questioning, though, is about Objective-C ARC and class methods)

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to the [OpenGL ES Programming guide's section on texturetool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html),

> Your app must parse the data header to obtain the actual texture data. See the
>   [PVRTextureLoader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008121) sample for an example of working with texture data in the PVR format.

This is all well and good, but 3 years later, and `PVRTextureLoader`'s `PVRTexture.m` doesn't compile because it needs to be converted in order to work in an ARC project. I reckon I could flag these two files as non-ARC but I wanted to at least learn a little about Objective-C this time around.

Here's a bit of code that's giving me trouble at this point:

```
+ (id)pvrTextureWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
{
    return [self initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

This was manually converted from:

```
+ (id)pvrTextureWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
}
```

Maybe someone could be so kind as to walk through what this actually does (as it makes no sense to me to refer to `self` from what is clearly declared as a class method and not an instance method), but the actual error seen is

```
<...>/PVRTexture.m:256:15: error: no known class method for selector 'initWithContentsOfFile:'
        return [self initWithContentsOfFile:path];
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

As for why I am manually converting this file to ARC, the **Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC...** menu option basically says "fix these 8 errors before I can continue" and these 8 errors are of course ARC-related errors. Which I was hoping the conversion would be able to resolve. Circular dependencies are only fun the first time around.

The curious bit is that `-initWithContentsOfFile:path` is *right there* in the file too:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        _imageData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

        _name = 0;
        _width = _height = 0;
        _internalFormat = GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_IMG;
        _hasAlpha = FALSE;

        if (!data || ![self unpackPVRData:data] || ![self createGLTexture])
        {
            self = nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

Note: This code compiles if I change the `+` to a `-` on the `pvrTextureWithContentsOfFile` declaration. I am positive the original code had a `+` there, so please, somebody help explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I think. Here's another example where writing out the question leads to the answer.

It's this:

```
return [[self alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I'm sure Google will be happy enough to (let SO) show me what `alloc` actually does. I guess calling `[self alloc]` from a class method is essentially what makes that method into a factory method that can generate instances of that class. This is nothing other than the Obj-C way to `new` something.

Me, I made the mistake of assuming `alloc` was something that ARC abolished.

Also, a side note: Reading carefully helps. I also just found out about [`GLKTextureLoader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GLKTextureLoader) so I didn't need to convert PVRTextureLoader at all.

Comment: Nope, `release`, `retain`, `autorelease` and calling `dealloc` on `super` are all abolished. `alloc` survives since there'd be no other way to do what it does — get a new instance from a class.

Comment: Well it could be [`new`ed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/719877/340947), eh? (though, not what I would want to use in this situation)

Comment: Technically yes, since `NSObject` isn't necessarily compiled with ARC so can call any other abolished method it likes (and you could even write a non-ARC category on `NSObject` with a method called `releaseSecretly` that just called `release` and call that from ARC code if you really wanted to break your program), but `new` is a bit useless so it'd be odd if things had gone that way. I don't think it's anything more than a Smalltalk holdover.

Comment: I'm now starting to worry about `[self release]; self = nil;` being converted to `self = nil;` becoming a bug (the `initWithContentsOfFile` function above). Will `self = nil` be doing something subtly wrong, or is it still correctly dealloc'ing the instnace on account of it being an init-method? (cross-reference: Second comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768136/340947)) also thanks for sticking around to comment.

Answer (score 1):

alloc is a class method. You usually see alloc used from another class, with things like:

```
NSView *myView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: someRect];
```

In a class method, self is the class, not an instance of that class. So [self alloc] allocates an instance of the class. It would also be valid to use the name of the class explicitly, so in the case of your PVRTexture class,

```
return [[self alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Could be replaced with

```
return [[PVRTexture alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Both are perfectly valid. I would probably use the second form, just because, like you, I find the first form a little odd-looking.

Comment: Curiously enough this sample code isn't even consistent in this regard, and the next method which is `pvrTextureWithContentsOfURL` ends with `return [PVRTexture pvrTextureWithContentsOfFile:[url path]];`